# What does "semi-public service" mean in Android?

Tags: java, android, service

I searching a way how to disable the opening and closing animation of notification bar (status bar). The behavior and animation is hardcoded in `StatusBarService`. The documentation says that the StatusBarService is "semi-public". What does "semi-public service" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semi-public, meaning that the public only has access to parts of the service.  There will be certain functionality that you cannot modify, and some you can.  Another example of semi-public functionality is found around `KeyCode`, in which the `KEYCODE_HOME` is never sent to applications in order to protect users against malicious applications.